# Do some physicists believe that the universe is a three-dimensional space wrapped on a four-dimension doughnut?

Tags: cosmology

> The astrophysicists believe if this is true, the universe would be
> finite. The entire cosmos may be only three or four times larger than
> the limits of the observable universe, which is about 45 billion
> light-years away. If true, a doughnut-shaped universe also has the
> possibility of allowing a spaceship that goes in one direction to
> eventually return to where it started without turning around.
>
> The shape of the universe is something that astronomers have been
> debating for decades. Some believe the universe is flat where parallel
> lines stay parallel forever. Others believe the universe is closed,
> being the parallel lines eventually intersect. Astronomers say the
> geometry of the universe dictates its fate.
>
> While open universes continue to expand forever, a closed universe
> eventually collapses in on itself. Observations focusing on cosmic
> microwave background, which is the flash of light released when the
> universe is only 380,000 years old, have established that our universe
> is flat and parallel lines will stay parallel forever with an
> ever-evolving universe. However, there’s more to shape than geometry,
> and topology has to be considered. Topology allows shapes to change
> while maintaining the same geometric rules.
>
> An example is a sheet of flat paper that has parallel lines that stay
> parallel. If you roll the paper into a cylinder, the parallel lines
> are still parallel. If you take that sheet of paper and connect the
> opposite ends while it’s rolled like a cylinder, you get the shape of
> a doughnut, which is still geometrically flat. The team believes the
> warping occurs beyond observational limits and will be very difficult
> to detect. The team was looking at perturbations, which describe bumps
> and wiggles in the cosmic microwave background radiation temperature.
> They believe there could be a maximum size to the perturbations that
> could reveal the universe’s topology. Buchert and his team emphasize
> their results are preliminary and note that instrument effects could
> explain some of their results.

https://www.slashgear.com/astrophysicists-believe-the-universe-may-be-shaped-like-a-giant-3d-doughnut-20683133/

Do some physicists believe that the universe is a three-dimensional space wrapped on a four-dimension doughnut? I was reading this article and was confused about the geometry being discussed, they say the universe is flat, not in the sense that it's two-dimensional, but in the sense that parallel lines remain parallel indefinitely, then they mention that it's wrapped on a doughnut, which is impossible unless they mean a four-dimensional doughnut which would allow parallel lines to join, is this what is being said here? A topological three-dimensional plane wrapped on a fourth-dimensional doughnut would retain its geometrical feature like a two-dimensional plane wrapped on a three-dimensional doughnut would.

Comment: Yes, that model has the topology of a 4D doughnut. It's like a 3D version of a game where if you go off the top of the screen you reappear at the bottom. But that doesn't *necessarily* mean that there's a 4th spatial dimension.